# Which approach is better: function.apply(<this>, args) or having a function to accept <this> as argument?

Tags: javascript

Let's say that I have a functionA defined like this:

```
functionA = function(myObject, someParams) {
  myObject.save_some_data = someParams;
  myObject.processed = true;
}
```

I can then call it and pass an object to work on as `functionA(someObject, someParams)`.

I can, however, transform this example with `apply()`:

```
functionA = function(someParams) {
  this.save_some_data = someParams;
  this.processed = true;
}

functionA.apply(someObject, [someParams]);
```

Both approaches seems to be achieving the same goal, or am I missing something?

But since `apply()` does exist in JavaScript, what are the benefits of using it instead of having my functions accept `this` as a first argument?

Comment: I would never use `apply` if not necessary. It makes the code harder to read, IMHO

Comment: in case you're still interested in the question, I've just updated my answer with several more practical examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call / apply are useful when you need to call an existing method of some object A in context of (as if it was defined on) another object B.

For example:

```js
var john = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  first_name: function() { return this.name.split(' ')[0] }
}

var jane = {
  name: 'Jane Doe',
}

john.first_name.call(jane) // reuse method from john 
                           // as if it was defined for jane 
                           // (will return 'Jane')
```

*[UPDATE]*

Of course, that was just an artificial example to illustrate the idea, but there are a lot of reasonable applications for call / apply methods. Below is just a few examples:

### 1. Simplifying client code

Imagine you want to add method `fname` to object `jane = {name: 'Jane Doe'}` that should let you do the following:

```js
jane.fname(function() { return this.name[0] }) // => J
jane.fname(function() { return this.name.split(' ')[1] }) // => Doe
```

You can try one of the following approaches:

```js
// (1) naive (wrong!) approach:
jane.fname = function(callback) { return callback() } 
// problem: the callback function won't know that `this` == jane
jane.fname(function() { return this.name  }) // => undefined

// (2) straightforward approach:
jane.fname = function(callback) { return callback(this) }
jane.fname(function(self) { return self.name  }) // => Jane Doe

// (3) call / apply approach
jane.fname = function(callback) { return callback.call(this) }
jane.fname(function() { return this.name  }) // => Jane Doe
```

As can be seen, both the straightforward (2) and the call / apply (3) approaches work as expected, but the latest one is optimized for "external" usage, which can be very useful in libraries (think about jQuery)

## 2. Passing array instead of list of parameters

Another example. We have an array of numbers:

```js
var numbers = [5, 6, 2, 3, 7];
```

And we want to find the biggest one of them. Now, we do have a Math.max function, but we can't use it easily because it doesn't accept an arbitrary array of numbers: `Math.max(5, 6)` and `Math.max(5, 6, 2, ...)` are possible, but `Math.max(numbers)` is not. Luckily we can use apply to circumvent this constraint:

```js
Math.max.apply(null, numbers); 
// we could use any object instead of null in this case, 
// because Math.max doesn't depend on the this object
```

As you see, we may use `apply` to effectively convert an array to a list of arguments. (But be careful with large arrays: there's a risk of exceeding the JavaScript engine's argument length limit; more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#apply_and_built-in_functions))

## 3. Constructor chaining

That is probably a most important use case:

```
// constructor for a NamedEntity "class":
function NamedEntity(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

function Person(first_name, last_name) {
  this.last_name = last_name;
  // reuse NamedEntity's constructor:
  NamedEntity.call(this, first_name + ' ' + last_name);
}

var john = new Person('John', 'Doe')
john.name // => John Doe
```

---

It worth mentioning that starting from ECMAScript 5 there's also a `bind` function, semantically related to `call` and `apply`, which let us do even [more interesting things](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Another scenario is using Array instance methods on objects which aren't Array instances, but do behave like them. For example a NodeList can be indexed like an array, and has a length property, but doesn't have the methods of Array instances. We can still use those Array instance methods on a NodeList by using call: `Array.prototype.slice.call(nodelist, 0, 10); // select only the first 10 nodes`. Using Array instance methods on the `arguments` object is another scenario.

Answer (score 3):

`apply` is going to use `someParams` as an array of arguments; `call` would actually do the same thing:

```
functionA.call(someObject, someParams);
```

There are no benefits except for style. Passing `someObject` as an argument is probably going to make more sense in most cases, but it’s really up to you and which one you like best.

Comment: Sorry, of course I meant array of someParams. I will edit my question.

Comment: So, the only reason for `apply()/call()` is style?

Comment: @mishik: Not always, but if you’re the one who has the choice where to use it and how to write it, then yes, I’d say so.

Comment: `call` and `apply` are needed to use a method on an object different from its native object type.